# Is ther any alternatives for data validation of user input

Tags: php

Is `preg_match()` a reliable function to use it on its own to validate input data? just for validation(I am not talking about sanitizating  and escaping).

For example:
I want to allow only letters and numbers from a user input. To make sure that this happens i will use `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$_POST["input"])`.
apart from client side (js) and `filter_input()`(php) validation is there any other method to validate data?

thanks

EDIT: i meant very reliable method (the best ), I know that there other ways around to validate.

Comment: Is your question if there is any other way or any other way that is better? Better, no in my opinion. Other ways, yes. You could loop through each character and use is_numeric() or ctype_alpha(). But it's not better

Comment: After your edit, I think "the best" way to do validation is fairly subjective.

Comment: your regx will allow empty as well `/^$/`

Answer (score 2):

You should use [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) or [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for validation.  You can use range of pre-defined [validation filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) or specify your custom filter with [filter callback](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php).

Comment: there is no filter to match letters and number

Comment: Yes, there is - FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP

Comment: What would be the advantage of using filter_input or filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP over just using preg_match?

Comment: You can specify validation for the whole form using `$definition` in case of `filter_input` or `filter_input_array`. In case of single item validation I don't see any advantage.